# Git - Move the contents of a file into another directory

Tags: git

How does one move the contents of a directory or a single file to another directory?

I did the following `git mv Jarryd/movementcommands.c src`

and got this
`fatal: not under version control, source=Jarryd/movementcommands.c, destination=src/movementcommands.c`

How should it be moved?

like this `git mv Jarryd/movementcommands.c src/movementcommands.c` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both forms should work but because your source file isn't under git's control you don't need `git mv`, a simple move and add is needed. (I assume that both Jarryd and src are in your git working tree.)

```
mv Jarryd/movementcommands.c src
git add src/movementcommands.c
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that `Jarryd/movementcommands.c` file or `src` folder are tracked by git?

Anyway you can try just

`mv Jarryd/movementcommands.c src`

```
git add src/movementcommands.c
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that both the source and destination directories are under git version control, like the error message says.

Also, this probably won't work if you're trying to move something out of a git submodule. I don't think git is designed to track that. (If you don't know what this paragraph means, it doesn't apply to you.)

Answer (score 1):

Note that before With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), "[`git mv src dst`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/be2dab9c801fe28a6937e8d426f891e610a82a49/Documentation/git-mv.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv))</sup>, when `src` is an unmerged path, errored out correctly but with an incorrect error message to claim that `src` is not tracked.

Meaning `fatal: not under version control` did not always means "untracked".

See [commit 9b906af](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9b906af657d4ec0bc8fc01c5cbbbddb582a8cac6) (20 Jul 2020) by [Chris Torek (`chris3torek`)](https://github.com/chris3torek).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit be2dab9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be2dab9c801fe28a6937e8d426f891e610a82a49), 30 Jul 2020)</sup>

> ### [`git-mv`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9b906af657d4ec0bc8fc01c5cbbbddb582a8cac6): improve error message for conflicted file
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Chris Torek</sup>

> '[`git mv`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9b906af657d4ec0bc8fc01c5cbbbddb582a8cac6/Documentation/git-mv.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv))</sup> ' has always complained about renaming a conflicted file, as it cannot handle multiple index entries for one file. However, the error message it uses has been the same as the one for an untracked file:
>
> ```
> fatal: not under version control, src=...
> ```
>
> which is patently wrong.
> Distinguish the two cases and add a test to make sure we produce the correct message.

Then new error message, in case you are moving a file with conflict during a merge/rebase, will be:

```
fatal: conflicted
```

which is better than:

```
fatal: not under version control
```

---

However...

Git 2.31.1 (Q1 2021) fixes a corner case bug in "[`git mv`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ef486a9ecfc73512d515644cc02f7ad9a229c533/Documentation/git-mv.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv))</sup> on case insensitive systems, which was introduced in 2.29 timeframe.

Example of 2.29/2.30/2.31 issue:

```sh
c:\git_CAP\repo_MFW2>git mv mfw2/application/phaseCalc_IQ_Xiong.hpp PC_phaseTest/phaseCalc_IQ_Xiong.hpp
Assertion failed: pos >= 0, file builtin/mv.c, line 295
```

See [commit 93c3d29](https://github.com/git/git/commit/93c3d297b5060a59715b8e8bc719d8e60ecf8106) (01 Mar 2021) by [Torsten Bögershausen (`tboegi`)](https://github.com/tboegi).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ef486a9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef486a9ecfc73512d515644cc02f7ad9a229c533), 19 Mar 2021)</sup>

> ### [`93c3d297b5`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/93c3d297b5060a59715b8e8bc719d8e60ecf8106):`git mv foo FOO` ; `git mv foo bar` gave an assert
>
> <sup>Reported-By: Dan Moseley</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Torsten Bögershausen</sup>

> The following sequence, on a case-insensitive file system, (strictly speeking with `core.ignorecase=true`) leads to an assertion failure and leaves `.git/index.lock` behind.
>
> [`git init`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/93c3d297b5060a59715b8e8bc719d8e60ecf8106/Documentation/git-init.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init))</sup> echo foo >foo [`git add`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/93c3d297b5060a59715b8e8bc719d8e60ecf8106/Documentation/git-add.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add))</sup> foo [`git mv`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/93c3d297b5060a59715b8e8bc719d8e60ecf8106/Documentation/git-mv.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv))</sup> foo FOO `git mv` foo bar
>
> This regression was introduced in commit [9b906af](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9b906af657d4ec0bc8fc01c5cbbbddb582a8cac6) (`git-mv`: improve error message for conflicted file, 2020-07-20, Git v2.29.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be2dab9c801fe28a6937e8d426f891e610a82a49) listed in [batch #1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/79bcaf006215b91de981c30c0268467e06faaf39)).
>
> The bugfix is to change the "file exist case-insensitive in the index" into the correct "file exist (case-sensitive) in the index".
>
> This avoids the "assert" later in the code and keeps setting up the "`ce`" pointer for `ce_stage(ce)` done in the next else if.
>
> This fixes [`git-for-windows/git` issue 2920](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2920)