# Git says "not under version control" for just-checked-out file

Tags: git

I have the distinct impression my Git repo is somehow mangled.

Here's the sequence I'm doing:

1. git clone [remote's clone string]

   This creates, among many others, a file "App/android/AndroidManifest.xml"
2. git mv App/android/AndroidManifest.xml App/android/AndroidManifestTemplate.xml

This gives the error message:

```
fatal: not under version control, source=App/And..."
```

Initially I thought this might be a gitignore thing, but that's not it either. I tried git fsck, it doesn't report anything.

Any suggestions on how to repair it?

Comment: You do step into the cloned directory first, right?

Comment: Yeah. Even when I'm right in the directory of the file and do a "git mv AndroidManifest.xml AndroidManifestTemplate.xml", it gives me the error

Comment: what does `ls App/android/AndroidManifest.xml` give you?

Comment: The file itself exists normally on my hard drive, so the above ls command works normally and lists that file.

Comment: What does `git status` say?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Maybe `App/android/AndroidManifest.xml` does exist, but with a diferent case (like `App/android/androidmanifest.xml`, which would mean that `App/android/AndroidManifest.xml` isn't versioned (hence the error message):

Doing the `git mv` with the right case should then be enough.

The [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3512600/user3512600) explains [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385447/git-says-not-under-version-control-for-just-checked-out-file/26385646#comment41429162_26385646):

> What happened was that there were two folders in Git, "`App`" and "`app`".
>   When I checked out the repo under Windows, because of the case-insensitivity of Windows, it actually overlayed the two folders into one into "`App`".
>   Which meant, the directory structure was fine, but half of the files (the ones coming from the "`app`" side) had an invalid Git path!

Comment: Use tab completion to be safe.

Comment: That was a good suggestion, since I'm checking out under Cygwin, but alas that didn't solve it either. No combination of lower/uppercase I tried made it work.

Comment: @user3512600 in that case, is that element really under version control? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/5754899/6309)

Comment: That's the thing, it's not! It gets created during the clone, so clearly it must be part of the repo, but a "git ls-tree HEAD" in the directory right after doesn't list it.

Comment: @user3512600 there must be some content filter driver at work (look for a `.gitattributes` file with a `smudge` directive in it) (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/20822928/6309)

Comment: After all, the upper/lower-case did indeed turn out to be the issue. What happened was that there were two folders in Git, "App" and "app". When I checked out the repo under Windows, because of the case-insensitivity of Windows, it actually *overlayed* the two folders into one into "App". Which meant, the directory structure was fine, but half of the files (the ones coming from the "app" side) had an invalid Git path!

Comment: @user3512600 great feedback. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I had a similar problem with Git Shell. I was able to upload changes to github for a file but it gave this error. The problem was, I was typing "cd shuffling" when the correct capitalization was Shuffling. So case-insensitive Windows let me go to "shuffling" but case-sensitive git saw "cd shuffling;git mv map.trizbort maps" as wrong because there was no shuffling\map.trizbort, only Shuffling\map.trizbort.

This is slightly different from @DoktorSchrott's issue, but it's another way inconsistent case sensitivity can cause confusion. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 6):

Another quirk that left me frustrated is if you're using the command line, it will use your current path to `git mv` the file. So if you have a file in `C:\Git\MyRepo\MyFolder\MyFile.txt`

If you do:

`c:`

`cd git`

`cd myrepo`

`cd myfolder`

`dir`

It will work fine, you'll see your file. But if you type `git mv MyFile.txt MyFile2.txt` you will get an error because git can't find Myfile.txt.

The reason is that it's looking at your current path, which is `c:\git\myrepo\myfolder\`

But git is case sensitive. So you have to go back and type

`c:`

`cd Git`

`cd MyRepo`

`cd MyFolder`

If you then type git mv it will work fine.

Putting this in as an answer for people like me that found this post while debugging this error message.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I was trying everything that made sense and I didn't even notice that it was a case situation with the _path_ instead of the filename.

Answer (score 2):

Most easiest way to solve this issue is to first we need to add the file first and then we need to rename the file

$ git add file-name

$ git mv current-file-name new-file-name

and then your problem will be solve.
[image: Screenshot for above issue]

Answer (score 0):

The situation encountered by the OP, as described in the [currently chosen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26385646), is caused by 2 pre-existing folders (or file names, for that matter) have same spelling but different case. That was a bad naming choice in the first place, and hopefully won't happen very often.

Here, for the sake of completeness, the same "not under version control" error message can also happen when using **git bash on Windows**, when you did not specify the old file name with precise correct case.

Example:

1. Assuming there is a file path contains mixed case `Dir/MyVeryLongFileName.txt` in your repo, and git will store its file path in a case-sensitive way.
2. Now you type `git mv dir/MyV` <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Let's say you did not use TAB auto-completion for the path `dir`, probably because it is short enough to type, and you did not notice that you incorrectly typed its first letter as `d` rather than `D`.
3. Since Windows is case-insensitive, the TAB auto-completion would still work, so you now have this in the command-line

   ```
   $ git mv dir/MyVeryLongFileName.txt
   ```

   Now you go ahead to finish your command, and, BOOM, you get the error:

   ```
   $ git mv dir/MyVeryLongFileName.txt somewhere/else/
   fatal: not under version control, source=dir/MyVeryLongFileName.txt, destination=somewhere/else/MyVeryLongFileName.txt
   ```

   In fact, if you use the same style to type `ls dir/MyV`<kbd>Tab</kbd> for your investigation, the bash will tell you that old file exists (despite its actually wrong case spelling), which is misleading.

All these above are not rocket science, but it woudl be tricky enough to raise your blood pressure when you were racing with time to get your PR ready. #LearnInTheHardWay

The moral of the story? Use TAB auto-completion even after you already type a dir name. In the example above, typing `git mv dir`<kbd>Tab</kbd> will automatically fix that incorrect case for you and you will get `git mv Dir/`. Keep using <kbd>Tab</kbd> for each part of your path.

Comment: The `tab` save my life for hours of hours of researching.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers above are great, I found this when trying to move files, and Capitalize them *during the same commit*

By committing my new file path, I could access the new path and then `git mv` (:

problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Since git is case sensitive, but the OS is not, git thinks the path is wrong when it actually exists with different caps.

A programmatic way to fix this can be deleting the conflicting path from the OS and then doing a `git reset --hard HEAD` or checkout the directory from the HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

Got into this problem today. In my case it seems to be backslashes in the path that cause this issue.

I was trying to rename my file in `cmd` like this:

```
cd C:\Path\To\My\File
git mv file1.js file1.ts
```

This gave me this `Not under version control` error.

As soon as I switched to `git bash` instead of `cmd` and started to use linux-like forward slashed it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Observe if the stage is signed as UNTRACKED (git status).
Add the file (`git add name_of_file.ext`) and then try change again.

Answer (score 0):

Although my answer won't solve the problem initially raised, it might help someone at some point because I just solved the same problem in a Business Central project...

**I was getting this error** without being able to avoid it until I realized that **I had used an accented vowel** in the name of the folder containing the file...

`\app\Planificación`

After cleanly cloning the project back to another location and copying the contents of that new folder **WITHOUT the accented vowel** the problem is completely gone.

`\app\Planificacion`

Hope this can help someone...