# how do i add core.ignorecase to .gitattributes

Tags: git, gitattributes

I have a repo that need to be run both in windows and linux, so need to set `git config core.ignorecase false`

but instead of asking each developer to set this in their repo, I want to add this in `.gitattributes`

I tried two things and both didn't work

```
[core]
    ignorecase = false
```

and

```
* text=auto ignorecase=false
```

I checked the `.git/config` file and content is like this:

[image]

if I set it to `false`, I can see that vscode is picking files names changes. but when I set that in `.gitattributes` vscode doesn't pick the changes.

how should I set it only for this repository so all developers don't need to set it manually?

Comment: From git attributes document ( https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes ), I don't see anything about case sensitive or ignore case. I think that is not possible to do it in .gitattributes file.

Answer (score 2):

No, do not do this.  You cannot configure git to be case insensitive, despite what this setting's name suggests.

`core.ignorecase is not a configuration option; git detects whether your repository is on a case sensitive filesystem or not at initialization time. It saves this state in the configuration so that it doesn't have to needlessly requery over and over again, every time you run git.

Do not change `core.ignoreCase`.  There is no way to change the fact that an ext3 filesystem is case *sensitive* and that HFS+ and NTFS are case *insensitive* by default.  No setting to git can change this fact, and setting `core.ignoreCase` to the wrong value will break more things than you're trying to fix.

Comment: you are wrong. please try first. if in windows you set git.ignorecase=false, and have a file name abc.text and rename it to ABC.text. you will get a rename commit, otherwise it will be ignored.

Comment: That’s because you’ve told git you’re on a case insensitive filesystem, not because you’ve turned off some case sensitive mode option that means that your git operations will continue to make sense.  I didn’t say you *couldn’t* change this.  I said you *shouldn’t* change this.

Comment: this is the case that is happenning when you have a repo shared on both widnows and linux, I want to prevent this case happens https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385447/git-says-not-under-version-control-for-just-checked-out-file/26385646#26385646